# Why do bodybuilders take such a long recovery period?

Tags: cardio, bodybuilding, recovery

Why do bodybuilders take recovery periods that are longer than any other type of athlete?

Im doing a mixture of weights and cardio. I try to do 2 sessions with weights focusing on upper body and 2 cario sessions (with some high resistant) a week. If I do weights on monday and I want to do cardio to tuesday, should I avoid the rowing machine?

Comment: Hi! Is your question really just about how much rest you should get between your weight and cardio sessions and how hard you can go during your cardio sessions? If so, you can simplify this question a lot by taking out the bodybuilder question.

Comment: Its more complicated than that. My cardio sessions are high resistance and so also anaerobic. The rowing machine is cardio, anaerobic and upper and lower body. So if I use the rowing machine in either work out im going to be working some muscles more frequently than bodybuilding would normally reccomend.

Comment: Those details about your situation will make this a much better question. Also, what is your goal? Bodybuilding? Fat loss? Strength training?

Comment: Bodybuilding and Fat loss

Comment: And I want to improve my posture. Im keen to use the rowing machine as I can feel it working by back muscles all the way up my spine.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include all of this, and remove the unnecessary? Also, please describe your lifting program (what exercises, weights used, etc.). I think you'll get a much better answer this way.

Comment: Anything that is cardiovascular IS AEROBIC. You can do anaerobic sprints (100m) but much further than that is all aerobic. Anaerobic means "without oxygen," and for cardiovascular workouts to take place they have to be aerobic (with oxygen). If you do short burst, power exercises that alone are anaerobic, but strung together in succession they become aerobic.

Comment: @Grohlier Strung together with rest periods, sprints (or (bar/kettle/dumb)bell complexes) retain a significant anaerobic component, no?

Comment: @Dave Liepmann, did I miss the rest periods part?  If so, my fault and yes, you are correct.  If there are rest periods that let the ATP-PC system reset you can maintain an anaerobic workout.  If there is no rest period (think circuit-training) it becomes aerobic as the ATP-PC and Cori-Krebs cycles run their course and can no longer meet the needs of the exercise.

Comment: I'm not sure bodybuilders do take longer rest periods than any other type of athlete. Sprinters often take many minutes of rest between their maximum effort sprints in a training session. Olympic lifters sometimes take many minutes of rest between even single reps.

Comment: I mean in the sense that they only train each body part every 3 or 4 days.

Comment: @Grohlier - Actually, the Krebs cycle is aerobic. It takes over after the ATP-PC (up to 10 seconds in duration) and the Cori cycle (Efforts up to 2 minutes, also known as anaerobic glycolysis) are finished.

Comment: JohnP, you are mostly correct. First thing is I miss spoke and you are correct.  The Krebs cycle is aerobic and the Cori cycle is anaerobic.  However, the Krebs cycle takes over after the Cori cycle, not after the ATP-PC.

Answer (score 1):

After doing strength training, the body's levels of Human Growth Hormones rise, and tend to stay elevated for approximately 48 hours.  During this time your body sees the most muscle growth.  So bodybuilders tend to tried to schedule a major strength training session every 48 hours to keep the Growth Hormone levels continuously high.
Additionally, to achieve maximum growth a muscle needs some time to rest, as strength gains are made during recovery.
That being said,  for most of us who are mostly trying to improve overall fitness,  having a cardio exercise that happens to work the same muscles on the off days should not hurt you, and probably will help reduce Delayed On-Set Muscle Soreness.  Just make sure that you occasionally have a complete rest day to allow for fuller recovery.